# IOS Guess mime type

Tags: ios, react-native, mime-types

One of the react native projects I'm working on uses a package called react-native-background-upload.

One of the native modules uses this line of code to determine the mimetype:

```
- (NSString *)guessMIMETypeFromFileName: (NSString *)fileName {
CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)[fileName pathExtension], NULL);
CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
CFRelease(UTI);
if (!MIMEType) {
    return @"application/octet-stream";
}
return (__bridge NSString *)(MIMEType);
}
```

The input going into it fileName value is: 
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=A7F5245E-C08E-4FB5-B7BE-0AB689B16DC5&ext=JPG

This however always returns "application/octet-stream". It should return "image/jpeg"

I think this guessMIMETypeFromFileName fucntion is broken.

I do not know native IOS code to fix this.

Comment: I think you best remove the questionmark and everything behind it from the filename

Comment: @dentemm not sure how to do that in objc.

Comment: Is there a possibility to alter the fileName in your JavaScript code before you send it to the native module?

Comment: Otherwise I will provide a ObjC snippet to parse the url

Comment: `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=A7F5245E-C08E-4FB5-B7BE-0AB689B16DC5&ext=JPG` is not a file name. That is a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[fileName pathExtension]` with:

```
[[fileName pathExtension] componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"][0]
```